# How do I split a file in multiple files with same number of lines via CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Windows CMD

How do I split a file story.txt with random number of lines into multiple files of 10 lines each named:

chapter.1.txt

chapter.2.txt

chapter.3.txt

etc (until it ends)

Using windows cmd

Thanks

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Split-large-log-6f2c4da0

Comment: Hello, never used powershell, but if there could be some help on how to call powershell by cmd thats good enough, will work. If when you have time could help with this would thank you, if you could reply in some days in your or in your possible time I could wait. Thank you very much

Comment: @MIke If by cmd, you mean in a batch file, you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19335004/3395469).

Comment: Didnt find where they say how to split the file in x lines. This other post if just for how to call powershell via cmd right?